# Turn off output flag from callback in Python/Gurobi

Tags: python, callback, gurobi

Is there any way to turn off the output from a callback in Python/Gurobi?
Specifically, while doing Branch and Cut.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can modify **OutputFlag**, which controls the Gurobi output. Setting OutputFlag to 0 will suppress solver output.

Link to the OutputFlag documentation [here](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/refman/outputflag.html#parameter:OutputFlag).
Link to other Gurobi flags [here](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/refman/parameters.html).

Hope this helps Seba!